# Rails 3 Routing based on regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to redirect all routes that start with the string xyz to some other path.

```
match /\/xyz\/(.)*/ => redirect{ "whateverurl" }
```

The match method doesn't seem to work when given a regex, I have googled alot seems like there are options to do with regex but they are for params for example

```
match 'photos/:id' => 'photos#show', :constraints => { :id => /[A-Z]\d{5}/ }
```

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
match '/xyz/*foo' => redirect('url')
```

It's not a regexp, it's called *route globbing*. More about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments).